# Comprar valores da lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

estou tendo um probleminha com uma lista.

Tenho que um txt com algumas informações (log de falha de um sistema) e queria que o python imprimisse pra mim essa falhas com a "tradução" delas exemplo:

Se cod_erro == '1':
   print('Senha invalida')

e por ai vai... segue o código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
row = []
li = []
x = 0 
y = 0
count = []
with open("Txts/test3.txt", "r") as arq:
    for linha in arq:
        if linha.find('Failed') > -1:
            li += linha.split(': ') #li recebe todos os valores separados pelo split ou seja li vai ter o valor anterior + o novo valor gerando assim uma lista conforme o numero de palavras que tem no texto
            li = [item.replace("\n", "") for item in li]

y = len(li)
#print(li[x]) #colocar [x] x = numero para printar o valor especifico

while x != y :
    #print('oi') #teste pra ver se ia executar a quanitdade de vezes correta
    print(li[x]) #Teste pra ver se iria printar os valores alocados  
    if li[x] == '1':
        print('Apenas um teste')
        break    
    x = x + 1
```

meu problema é que o Python parece não estar entrando na condição do IF (se eu printar a li[1] o valor será '1' porém o if não funciona com esses valores)

PORÉM TODA VIA E ENTRE TANTO: se eu colocar assim if li[x] == 'Failure' ele entra na condição.....

@@EDIT: O if não funciona quando o erro retornado é um numero, caso seja uma letra ele funciona normalmente

Comment: Pode colocar um trecho do arquivo de log? Acredito que este código possa ser melhorado bastante. Aliás, o que aparece na tela devido ao `print(li[x])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você já observou em sua pergunta, a comparação está sendo realizada com a string 1 e não com o inteiro, existe uma diferença entre if x == '1' (compara a string 1) e if x == 1 (compara o inteiro 1).

Acho que se você melhorar a condicional de seu if dessa forma já resolva o seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas na verdade o meu spit tava gerando um \n \r no final entao ele nao comparava mas ja resolvi vlw